# How to change istio ingress loadbalancer external IP

Tags: kubernetes-ingress, istio, nginx-ingress, azure-load-balancer

I want to change my istio ingress loadbalancer IP but when i try updating the yaml file it is not getting updated

```
NAME                       TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP
istio-ingressgateway       LoadBalancer   10.123.196.149   52.174.141.126
```

I have to change my EXTERNAL-IP to different IP.

Comment: This depends on the load balancer provider, and thus on how you deploy the cluster, and on the cloud provider you use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is that copy the configuration of the service `istio-ingressgateway` and then delete the service. In the configuration file, delete the `uuid`, the `creationTimestamp` line, and delete the status property. Then recreate the service from the configuration file. It will work for you.

Comment: where should i give/change my external ip.

Comment: @pappu_kutty You do not get the public IP before creation. Just delete the status property and it will create itself for you. Then you will get the external IP through the command `kubectl get service -n namespace`.

Comment: but my question is how to change my ip address.. which my applications are already pointing to.. since update or new istio creation will generate new ip, but i need old ip, which my applications are pointing to

Comment: @pappu_kutty That's no problem. You also can set the public IP with the old one that you want. But if you use the old one it means a static IP. So you may pay attention to permission if the public is not in the same group with your AKS cluster. Take a look at [the static IP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/ingress-static-ip) and the [note](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/static-ip#use-a-static-ip-address-outside-of-the-node-resource-group).

Comment: @pappu_kutty I'm wondering if you could fix this? If so how? I tried to install the istio by setting the static IP that I wanted however it still gets a random IP: helm template install/kubernetes/helm/istio --name istio --namespace istio-system --set grafana.enabled=true --set prometheus.enabled=true --set tracing.enabled=true --set kiali.enabled=true --set controller.service.loadBalancerIP= "mystaticIP" | kubectl apply -f -   the static IP is created in Azure Public IP and assigned to kubernetes loadbalancer(LB). However by installing istio wth a random IP, the LB IP would get the random IP.

Answer (score 2):

Just run:

```
kubectl patch svc istio-ingressgateway --namespace istio-system --patch '{"spec": { "loadBalancerIP": "<your-reserved-static-ip>" }}'
```

Reference: https://knative.dev/docs/serving/gke-assigning-static-ip-address/#step-2-update-the-external-ip-of-istio-ingressgateway-service

Answer (score 0):

If the public IP that you own is `A.B.C.D`, you need to add this to the `spec` section of the `istio-ingressgateway` service:

```
  loadBalancerIP: A.B.C.D
```

You probably need to save that service's `yaml` or `json`, add the `loadBalancerIP` line, then delete the service, and finally create it using the saved `yaml`/`json`.